# Prove H is not a subspace of $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

$H=\{(a+b+2c,ab+c):a,b,c \in R\}$

Please, I need help. I can't solve one single problem on this subject. It just seems finding random counterexamples, I can't see nothing solid. Please help me.

Comment: You know what needs to be done.  You need to show either that the subset is not closed under vector addition or under scalar multiplication.  Give us some evidence that you've tried.

Comment: Subspace of what?  $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly $H \subset \mathbb R^2$.  On the other hand, if $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ you can take $a = x - 2y$, $b = 0$, and $c = y$ to find that $$(x,y) = (a + b + 2c, ab + c) \in H.$$  Thus $\mathbb R^2 \subset H$ so in fact $H = \mathbb R^2$. Something is missing in the problem statement.